# Rails: show images without image tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to show images without using <%= img_tag %>. So I tried following things

```
<img src="/images/bg/1.jpg" >
<img src="assets/images/bg/1.jpg" >
<img src="assets/bg/1.jpg" >
<img src="bg/1.jpg">
<img src="/bg/1.jpg">
```

This does not show the image. But if I do this

```
<%= image_tag("bg/1.jpg") %>
```

This works. But why it does not work with img tag. How can I make this work?

My image location `app/assets/images/bg/1.jpg`

**Note**:

```
<%= image_tag("bg/1.jpg") %>
outputs
<img src="/assets/bg/1-ed0a6edfcc008f66c22373e3d57a5c01.jpg" >
```

generated image link is not exactly the original image name

Comment: But why would you use `<img src="">`? The generated HTML will always be similar, irrespective of what you use.

Comment: Rails does asset fingerprinting (the added characters) for several reasons. I think you should be able to turn it off, but it wouldn't be advisable. I tend to disagree with some of Rails' magic wrappers, but `image_tag` is pretty much one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate link through `image_url` if you really want to use the plain `img` tag instead of fancy `image_tag` by Rails, and here is how:

```
<img src="<%= image_url('bg/1.jpg') %>">
```

Comment: Hi! this is not working either. I have added a note in my question